# check for unique value in list before appendng new entry to list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, append

I have a list like this:

```
[1, 2, 4, 5]
[2, 4, 3, 4]
[3, 3, 4, 5]
[4, 1, 1, 2]
```

I have a new entry i would like to append:

```
[4, 5, 2, 3]
```

When adding to the list, I would like to check for uniqueness in the first value of the last element.
So that if the first element is the same, the new row overites the old row to get this:

```
[1, 2, 4, 5]
[2, 4, 3, 4]
[3, 3, 4, 5]
[4, 5, 2, 3]
```

What is the best way to accoplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

Here you can use a list comprehension to return the sublist as it is, but if the first elements match, then return the new sublist instead.

```
l = [[1, 2, 4, 5],
     [2, 4, 3, 4],
     [3, 3, 4, 5],
     [4, 1, 1, 2]]

k = [4, 5, 2, 3]


#Compare if first element is same as that of k and return k instead of i
[k if i[0]==k[0] else i for i in l]
```

```
[[1, 2, 4, 5], 
 [2, 4, 3, 4], 
 [3, 3, 4, 5], 
 [4, 5, 2, 3]]
```